# Odd behaviour with byte[] C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been writing some code to create a byte array I will be sending over a socket to another process. However noticed some really odd behavior regarding my byte[].

The cout at the end prints out 99, however looking at my code, I couldn't find where the value is being set. I create a char array of size sendingSize which is a constant. I don't set the value 307200* 3 so I don't understand how it prints out with a value...

```
char tosend[sendingSize];
//Send over the frame
for(int i = 0; i < 307200; i++)
{
    tosend[i * 3] = (byte)imCopy[i/640][i%640].red;
    tosend[i * 3+1] = (byte)imCopy[i/640][i%640].green;
    tosend[i * 3+2] = (byte)imCopy[i/640][i%640].blue;
}

char *bytePointer = tosend;

cout<<(int)tosend[307200* 3]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code does not write any value into index `307200*3` (because the highest index your `for` loop reaches is `307199`). So you are reading some byte from memory beyond the declared size of your array. This is *undefined behaviour* and anything could happen.

Some other programming languages (such as Java) do automatic *range checking* on arrays and would throw an exception in this case. In C++, you are expected to do the right thing and the compiler doesn't generate range checking code for you.

Comment: Shouldn't it allocate memory for the array? I set the size as: int sendingSize = 307200*3 + (80 * 4); Which is larger than 307200*3.

Comment: Allocation does not mean it initializes your array to zero. This also answers why there will be no segmentation faults.

Comment: @Jkh2: I'm not sure how you expected us to know what the value of `sendingSize` is. My answer was based on the *assumption* that `sendingSize = 307200*3`. Memory allocated from the stack is *not* cleared before use, so if you don't set it, it's just some random value.